# Почему при вводе последнего символа происходит выделение в инпуте?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

При вводе в инут последнего символа (с вирт. клавиатуры) весь текст выделяется синим. Я думаю что скорее проблема в этом куске кода, который нужен , для совместной работы маски поля и вирт клавиатуры. Но где там ошибка не пойму.

Но я заметил , что если клацнуть в не инпута и при вводе с обычной клавиатуры текст не выделяется (скорее всего из за потери фокуса). Так что событие blur я попытался повесить в момент когда вводится последний символ в инпут, но и это не помогло. Подскажите , что можно сделать ?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    insertAtCaret: function(myValue) {
        return this.each(function(i) {
            if (document.selection) {
                //For browsers like Internet Explorer
                this.focus();
                var sel = document.selection.createRange();
                // console.log(sel)
                sel.text = myValue;
                console.log(sel.text)
                this.focus();
            } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
                //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
                var startPos = this.selectionStart;
                console.log(this.selectionStart)
                var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
                var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                //  console.log(scrollTop)
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);

                this.focus();
                this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
                this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
                this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            } else {
                this.value += myValue;
                this.focus();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Вот полный код : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/44/

Comment: 1. Поздравляю, вы смогли сэмулировать эвенты)
2. Перед выкладыванием JS кода, полезно его привести в нормальный вид, я пользуюсь этим http://jsbeautifier.org/ 
3. Выделение всего импута происходит также если убрать фокус-выделить в фокус, когда все цифры заполнены, неважно с виртуальной клавиатуры или с обычной. Видимо что-то происходит при этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем проблемы с выделением в функции `on("focus.mask", function() {`

Чтобы выделения не было:

```
.on("focus.mask", function() {
    if (!input.prop("readonly")) {
        clearTimeout(caretTimeoutId);
        var pos;
        focusText = input.val(), pos = checkVal(), caretTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            writeBuffer(), input.caret(pos); // ИСПРАВЛЕНО ТУТ
        }, 10);
    }
})
```

В старом коде было:

```
 pos == mask.replace("?", "").length ? input.caret(0, pos) : input.caret(pos);
```

Т.е. когда позиция совпадала с длинной маски (в вашем случае 19) происходило выделение всей строки.